# PyTorch - removing batch norm gives different model results in inference

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, transfer-learning

I removed the batch norm layers from the model and loaded the weights of all the other layers for inference. The predictions of the original model vs models without batch norm are not the same.

Is the difference caused by the removal of the batch norm?

```py
#load pretrained model
checkpoint = torch.load(restore_file)
pretrained_model = checkpoint['model']
pretrained_dict = pretrained_model.state_dict()

#create new model without batch norm
model = no_batch_model()
model_dict = model.state_dict()

# 1. filter out unnecessary keys
pretrained_dict = {k: v for k, v in pretrained_dict.items() if k in model_dict}

# 2. overwrite entries in the existing state dict
model_dict.update(pretrained_dict)

# 3. load the new state dict
model.load_state_dict(pretrained_dict)
```

Comment: the reason i got different results: i wasn't adjusting for the running mean from the layer